# servlet request.parameter() function returns null when i post post request using swift 4 and alamofire4

Tags: ios, servlets, swift4, alamofire

I was trying to do a post request from ios swift4 using alamofire4.And my server side is a servelet file.

The Swift4 code is as follows

```
var datasDicts = [String: Any]()
datasDicts["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber
datasDicts["tokenId"] = fcmDeviceToken
let parameters: Parameters = ["UploadData": datasDicts]
Alamofire.request(DDGeneralData.globalDatas.url+"/Sample", method: .post, parameters: Parameters, encoding: 
JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON
                    { (response:DataResponse) in
                        print("response result \(response.result)")
                }
            }
```

The request is successfully called the servlet but when i call request.getparameter(); it returns null. the servlet code is asfollows

```
 String json_data = request.getParameter("UploadData");
 System.out.println(config.getLogTime()+" DdbLogin json 
 parsed"+json_data);
```

how can i solve. when i read the request using request.reader i am able to get the string but request.getParameter() returns null